# What is the difference between Recursive proxy server and Non-Recursive proxy server?

Tags: session, proxy, sip

when we are calling from one SIP IP Phone to another SIP IP phone with **UNCONDITIONAL Call Forwarding** feature activated,We have 2 methods :
1)Through **Recursive** proxy server
2)Through **Non-Recursive** proxy Server

[Call Forward Unconditionally via Recursive proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSMkg.png)
[Call Forward Unconditionally via Non-Recursive proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEepf.png)

Answer (score 0):

A recursive proxy server will just forwards it as a normal call to the new destination. A recursive call forward has more server side processing cost but it is compatible with all sip devices.

A non-recursive proxy will reject the calls with 302 Moved Temporarily specifying the new destination in the Contact header, so the client will know that it have to initiate a new call to the new destination (if it supports call forwarding). A non-recursive proxy can operate with minimal processing cost as it just simply rejects the calls.

You can find some more details [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/sip/proxies/1-0/administration/guide/ver1_0/appbcf.html#wp1019113).

Comment: I would like to know the answer in general

Comment: I already posted the photos which contains the details that you have mentioned in your explanation.